# How to specify layered navigation filters order in magento?

Tags: magento, mage

I use Amasty shopby extension in magento. Is there way to reorder filters? For example, if I want to place color filter before price. How can I do it?

Is there way to do it in admin panel? Or maybe through db?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIRC, you do have the right to set the position of price filter in amasty extension. Make sure the price's position is smaller than color's position which you can set in `Manage attributes` section.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, please use `admin > catalog > attributes > manage attributes > color` and set the Position value. The only exception is for Categories, as they are not attributes.  You can set categories position at the `admin > system > settings > amasty > improved navigation` section.